# Reduce StaticLayout initialize time for text over 16,000 lines

Tags: android, pagination, textview, epub, staticlayout

I use StaticLayout to paginate my text to create an epub application and i have a text that has 16,000 lines.

The StaticLayout object is created about 6 seconds later and it's very slow.

How can I reduce this time or is there another way to use StaticLayout instead?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Thanks for your tip.